PySpark collect per-column count into column instead of row
I have a use case where I try to collect information about every column in a dataframe (e.g. counting the amount of None values in each column):
def fn_count_null_values_for_columns(p_df):
return p_df.select(
    *(psf.count_if(psf.col(c).isNull()).alias(c) for c in p_df.columns)
)

The function as I have written it would gather said information into a single row. However I would want this function to add some additional Information (e.g. a bool that is True if there are no Null values in the column).
Thus I was wondering if it is possible to collect information in columns instead of rows (without having to do an expansive .melt -> .pivot step everytime.
That I easily could calculate another statistic based on the already existing one and each column could have its own data type.
EDIT:
As requested I here is an example of the source Data:
cols = ['id', 'col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4']
dats = [['0000', None, None, None, 0],
    ['0001',   10,    2, "Wow", 0],
    ['0002',   20, None, "Fake", 0],
    ['0003',   30,    2, "Test", 0]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(dats, cols)

This gives you:

The function (fn_count_null_values_for_columns) creates the following dataframe:

Now I want to be able to gather the data directly into a column like this (allowing me to easily add further columns based on previous aggregates):

OR I would also be fine with adding a second row to the result (if I don't have to do the whole aggregation function again and then Union the two rows)

Please show an example data and expected output.

@Emma I added example data and hopefully was able to describe my expected output more clearly

You are looking for a transpose operation, which is not directly available on a spark dataframe due to it's distributed architecture. Make sure you apply the following only on a summary dataframe (which is small in size).
You can achieve this first by creating a map of column names and null count, and then by exploding the map into columns.
from pyspark.sql.functions import isnull, isnan, when, count, col, lit, create_map, explode
import itertools

cols = ['id', 'col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4']
dats = [['0000', None, None, None, 0],
    ['0001',   10,    2, "Wow", 0],
    ['0002',   20, None, "Fake", 0],
    ['0003',   30,    2, "Test", 0]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(dats, cols)
df.show()

+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  id|col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|0000| null| null| null|    0|
|0001|   10|    2|  Wow|    0|
|0002|   20| null| Fake|    0|
|0003|   30|    2| Test|    0|
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+

null_count_df = df.select([count(when(isnull(c) | isnan(c), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns])
null_count_df.show()

+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| id|col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  0|    1|    2|    1|    0|
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+

result_df = null_count_df.withColumn("col_nullcount_map", create_map(list(itertools.chain(*[(lit(c), col(c)) for c in null_count_df.columns])))) \
       .select(explode("col_nullcount_map").alias("column_name", "null_count"))
result_df.show()

+-----------+----------+
|column_name|null_count|
+-----------+----------+
|         id|         0|
|      col_1|         1|
|      col_2|         2|
|      col_3|         1|
|      col_4|         0|
+-----------+----------+


Thanks for the answer. I will quickly compare it to the .melt .pivot variant
